# Images return 412 (Precondition Failed) every other page load

Tags: html, local-storage

I use HTML 5 LocalStorage to store some HTML that includes images. When I pull from that cache using this code:

```
$('#mydiv').append(localStorage.getItem('html_cache')).fadeIn();
```

It works the first time fine, no errors. If I hit reload, I get this error:

> GET https://pbs.twimg.com/media/A7w5LkHCMAAft1N.jpg:thumb 412 (Precondition Failed)

Clearly something is different on the second page load, but I cannot seem to figure out what. When I inspect the source, it looks exactly the same to me.

I am not familiar with 412 Errors. Any idea's what is going on here or how I might track it down?

Comment: I am getting the same error, also specifically with twimg.com. The weird thing is that it works every other time (first, third, etc).

Comment: Ok... That makes me 99% certain it is a server error on their end.

Comment: I just posted the question on the Twitter API forum as well. https://dev.twitter.com/discussions/12747

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This was an issue on the Twitter side of things. Several people reported it and they eventually fixed it. I am no longer getting the error.

More info: http://dev.twitter.com/discussions/12747